# Is methylenecyclopropane a cycloalkene?

Tags: nomenclature, definitions

Are all compounds with a ring and double bonds considered cycloalkenes? Can the double bond be outside the ring in a cycloalkene (example: methylenecyclopropane)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, methylidenecyclopropane is not a cycloalkene.

According to the *[Glossary of class names of organic compounds and reactivity intermediates based on structure (IUPAC Recommendations 1995)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307),* the double bond of a cycloalkene has to be part of the ring:

> Unsaturated monocyclic hydrocarbons having one endocyclic double or one triple bond are called cycloalkenes and cycloalkynes, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

*until someone proves me wrong...*

I think this is a matter of perspective. In terms of nomenclature, <del>I would consider  methylenecyclopropane a cycloalkene</del> I defer to IUPAC, as pointed out by Loong's answer. In terms of reactivity, one usually thinks of double bonds outside of the ring as more reactive than when part of the ring (but there can be ring strain effects, too). But I cannot think of a reaction that would distinguish between methylenecyclopropane and methylcyclopropene.

For aromaticity, we have something: Addition of bromine to the double bonds of 5-Methylene-1,3-cyclohexadiene (*i.e.* toluene with one H moved from the methyl group to a ring C) would proceed, but for toluene, radical substitution on the methyl group or electrophilic aromatic substitution are the only sensible possibilities.

So my argument is this: it somewhat does not matter if methylenecyclopropane is a cycloalkene or not because the reactivity is not fundamentally different.

*... and you can reach a different conclusion.*